# Please provide the simplest example you can think of, of generators of time evolution and generalized coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, noethers-theorem, lie-algebra

I was reading the Wikipedia article about [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) and this thing popped out:

> Then the resultant perturbation can be written as a linear sum of the
>   individual types of perturbations
>
> $$\delta t = \sum_r \epsilon_r T_r \!$$
>    $$\delta \mathbf{q} = \sum_r \epsilon_r \mathbf{Q}_r ~$$
>
> where $\epsilon_r$ are infinitesimal parameter coefficients
>   corresponding to each:
>
> - generator $T_r$ of time evolution, and
> - generator $Q_r$ of the generalized coordinates.

But, when I clic on "generator" it leads me to the article about [Lie Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#The_exponential_map) which is by itself a topic in which I could spend weeks, to say the least.

I had once in my past discrete groups in a lecture and I am more or less conversant with elementary lagrangian mechanics, matrix calculus and elementary non-relativistic quantum mechanics (however not with that SU(?) stuff about rotation invariances yet). Is it possible that someone here provides a very short explanation of what those generators are, and the simplest mathematical example you can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us for simplicity address OP's question in the context of point mechanics where $q^i$ are generalized position coordinates on some manifold $M$ [instead of considering field theory with fields $\phi^{\alpha}(x)$]. Let us also for simplicity consider the special case where there are no horizontal/time transformations

$$\delta t ~=~ \sum_a \epsilon_{(a)} X_{(a)} ~=~ 0,$$

but only vertical transformations

$$\delta q^i ~=~ \sum_a \epsilon_{(a)} Y^i_{(a)}, $$

where $\epsilon_{(a)}$ are (infinitesimal) parameters.$^1$

In a nutshell, the generators $Y_{(a)}$ are [vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)

$$ Y_{(a)}~=~ \sum_i Y_{(a)}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i}. $$

The [Lie bracket of two vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) $[Y_{(a)},Y_{(b)}]$  is again a vector field. In certain cases, the generators/vector fields form a [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra).

*Example:* The generator for a translation in the $a$'th direction of position space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is

$$Y_{(a)}~=~\frac{\partial}{\partial q^a}, $$

with constant vector field components

$$  Y^i_{(a)}~=~\delta^i_a. $$

In this case, the generators $Y_{(a)}$ commute, so they form an Abelian Lie algebra.

--

$^1$ See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53496/2451) Phys.SE answer.